# How could we check if a column of a table is filtered or not, by formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to check whether a column of a table is filtered or not. The **data type** of the column is `Text`. I want to use worksheet Formulas, not `VBA macros`.

Something like this:

```
=If(IsFiltered(Table1[Field1]),A1,A2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNTA` together with `SUBTOTAL` that uses `COUNTA`:

```
=IF(COUNTA([Range])=SUBTOTAL(103,[RANGE],"No","Yes")
```

Note that the parameter value 103 for `SUBTOTAL` above tells `SUBTOTAL` to use `COUNTA` as the formula for its calculation. (See the [SUBTOTAL documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) for specifics.)

In these screenshots, B9 contains the above formula with [RANGE]=A2:A7.  So the formula for this example is

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2:A7)=SUBTOTAL(103,A2:A7),"No","Yes")
```

Not Filtered:
[image: Not Filtered]

Filterd:
[image: Filtered]

To check an entire column just change `[RANGE]` to a valid column reference.  So my example would change to:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A:A)=SUBTOTAL(103,A:A),"No","Yes")
```

Column A not filtered
[image: Col Not Filtered]

Column A filtered
[image: Col Filtered]

Comment: Good Solution Sir, I had preferred using `Structured References` here. And use : `=IF(COUNTA(TableF)>SUBTOTAL(3,TableF), "list filtered ["&SUBTOTAL(3,TableF)&" items]","Not filtered")`